# Angular how do you create specific routes only in development mode

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

How do I go about loading certain routes only in development mode. When I build with production mode enabled I want those routes to be disabled.

Does anyone have any good recommendations on how to accomplish this feature?
For Example, hide the route2 component below if on Development Mode.

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    data: { allowedRoles: ['Role1','Role2'] },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard/main',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'route2',
        loadChildren: './theme/route2/route2.module#route2Module'
      }
    ]
   }
```

Comment: maybe you can add another service to `canActivate` and disable the route based on mode

Comment: Add ``AuthGuard`` for child component as well. The ``AuthGuard`` should be activated upon the Dev mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your Angular Router code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    data: { allowedRoles: ['Role1','Role2'] },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard/main',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'route2',
        loadChildren: './theme/route2/route2.module#route2Module'
      }
    ]
   }
```

You are trying to achieve lazy loading using router and also enabled specific modules to be loaded only for dev environment(if my understanding is correct).
for this Angular Router provided a **Guard** called **CanLoad**.
CanLoad came to play when you doesn't want to load specific modules to the route for sake of lazy-loading. Whether CanActivate is used for component level Guarding but on that case its load the Module to the browser.

So change the code in this way:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    data: { allowedRoles: ['Role1','Role2'] },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard/main',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'route2',
        loadChildren: './theme/route2/route2.module#route2Module', // Don't want to load this module
        canLoad: [DevEnvGuard]
      }
    ]
   }


@Injectable()
class DevEnvGuard implements CanLoad {
  constructor() {}

  canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
    return !environment.prod; // if prod = false it will load module
  }
}
```

I think this is the approach.
If I am missing something let me know on Comments.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using [Lazy Modules](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration), use an additional `guard` (where you can check for the actual environment) inside the [`canActivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an array, you can set the array based on the environment in your environment.ts file.

```
//environment.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false
};

//environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

When importing, just use the environment.ts file because the `fileRepleacements` in `angular.json` will manage this for you out of the box.

```
...
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
...
```

So your implementation could be similar to:

```
const routes = [...production route set];
if (!environment.production) {
    routes.push(...dev route set);
}
```